# Standard measures for buildings in the US?

Tags: ceiling, building-regulations, architecture

I've been looking for a reference guide on standard measures for common building elements in the US. That includes:

- Standard ceiling height
- Standard wall thickness
- Standard door dimensions
- Standard window dimensions (single, double, etc)

Does anyone know where I can get such information?

Comment: I've found them in architecture and trade books at the library.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Ceiling height**: 8 feet (nominal; 92-5/8" stud length plus 4-1/2" of plates), 9 and 10 feet less common (108" and 120" studs); vaulted ceiling peaks as room size and slope dictate

**Wall thickness**: interior, 3-1/2" (nominal 2x4) plus half-inch drywall on both sides; exterior, 5-1/2" (nominal 2x6) plus half-inch drywall inside, half inch sheathing outside, and an exterior finish. Thicker walls uncommon with high-efficiency designs

**Doors**: 28" and 30" for interior (nominal interior jamb width), 36" for handicap-accessible homes, 32" and 36" for exterior (42" uncommon)

**Windows**: No standard. Common heights are on the half-foot between 3 and 7 feet, but most manufacturers will offer sizes at 2 inch increments. Common widths from 18 inches to 12 feet.

Answer (score 3):

I’d read *[Architectural Graphic Standards](https://www.thriftbooks.com/w/architectural-graphic-standards_charles-george-ramsey_robert-t-packard/268456/item/11066145/?mkwid=8Uu6tVx2%7Cdm&pcrid=70112893392&product=11066145&plc=&pgrid=21326766312&ptaid=pla-292433097096&utm_source=google_shopping&utm_content=8Uu6tVx2%7Cdm%7Cpcrid%7C70112893392%7Cpkw%7C%7Cpmt%7C%7Cproduct%7C11066145%7Cslid%7C%7Cpgrid%7C21326766312%7Cptaid%7Cpla-292433097096%7C&gclid=CjwKCAiA3OzvBRBXEiwALNKDP1Zpvxjq6or1FhrOMcfjZn7YjkuB88GBtssS6VHlpAEY8AZlcI65-RoCDtMQAvD_BwE#isbn=0471707805&idiq=11066145)*.

It has standard terms, dimensions, materials, etc. used in the design and construction industry for parking lots, wall construction, roofing, flashing, stairs, fireplaces, plumbing, heating, electrical, etc.

This book has been published for over a hundred years, so be sure to buy a new publication not an older one.

Answer (score 0):

To the extent that things are "standard" (which is highly variable) an architecture textbook or (for doors/windows) a manufacturer's catalog.

Comment: The "standard" doors are 24 to 36" in even numbers . Anything over 36" is custom order ; that is why large door ways usually use two doors. I got about half of the interior doors at 36" but I had to argue with the architect and framers all the way.

Answer (score 0):

Wall thickness is a little tricky, in a broad sweeping statement you might hear interior walls are 4", and exterior are 6". But a 4" stud is about 3.5" and will have at very least a layer of 1/2" drywall on each side, making it 4.5". Insignificant interior walls in a commercial buulding might have 2.5" thick metal studs.

Then fire rating and structural engineering will add to the size. An interior load bearing or wall with plumbing may be 6", fire rated wall may have thicker or multiple layers of drywall, exterior and sheer walls will have layers of OSB.

There really is not a specific accurate encompassing answer.